How to make validation triggered dynamically using Precognition VUE.jS Laravel
I have a project where validation is implemented to check if fields are filled with correct data. But the validation itself is triggered for some reason when the cursor is removed from the field, and the validation is delayed.
Can you help to solve the issue.
The validation itself for the form is made with the help of Precognition library on VUE.jS, Laravel, Inertiajs.
Video with the problem and code already attached.
I will be glad to have any help.
Link to a video of the validation bug: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AmC6aepIoXP4AXqbytE2DEYIyzEPyA-A/view?usp=sharing
My code:
ProfilRequest.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

class ProfilRequest extends FormRequest
{
  
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'first_name' => ['required','min:3'],
            'last_name' => ['required','min:3'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'lowercase', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique(User::class)->ignore($this->user()->id)],
        ];
    }
}

web.php
   Route::post('/edit-password', [AdminProfileController::class, 'update_password'])->name('admin.profile.update_password')->middleware([HandlePrecognitiveRequests::class]);
UpdatePasswordForm.vue
`
<script setup>
import InputError from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/InputError.vue';
import InputLabel from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/InputLabel.vue';
import PrimaryButton from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/PrimaryButton.vue';
import TextInput from '@/Pages/Admin/Components/TextInput.vue';
import { useForm } from 'laravel-precognition-vue-inertia';

import { ref } from 'vue';
import { trans } from "laravel-vue-i18n";
const passwordInput = ref(null);
const currentPasswordInput = ref(null);

const form = useForm('post', route('admin.profile.update_password'), {
    new_password: '',
    new_password_confirmation: '',
});
const submit = () => form.submit({
    
    preserveScroll: true,

});
</script>

<template>
    <section>
        <header>
            <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">{{trans("Update Password")}}</h2>


        </header>

        <form @submit.prevent="submit" class="mt-6 space-y-6">
            

            <div>
                <InputLabel for="password" :value="trans('New Password')" />

                <TextInput
                    id="new_password"
                    ref="passwordInput"
                    v-model="form.new_password"
                    type="password"
                    v-bind:class="{'border-rose-500' : form.invalid('new_password')}"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    @change="form.validate('new_password')"
                />

                <div v-if="form.invalid('new_password')" class="text-red-600">
                    {{ form.errors.new_password }}
                </div>

            </div>

            <div>
                <InputLabel for="password_confirmation" :value="trans('Confirm new password')" />

                <TextInput
                    id="new_password_confirmation"
                    v-model="form.new_password_confirmation"
                    type="password"
                    class="mt-1 block w-full"
                    v-bind:class="{'border-rose-500' : form.invalid('new_password_confirmation')}"
                    autocomplete="new-password"
                    @change="form.validate('new_password_confirmation')"
                />

                <div v-if="form.invalid('new_password_confirmation')" class="text-red-600">
                    {{ form.errors.new_password_confirmation }}
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="flex items-center gap-4">
                <PrimaryButton :disabled="form.processing" >{{trans('Save')}}</PrimaryButton>

                
            </div>
        </form>
    </section>
</template>`

AdminProfileController.php

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\ProfileUpdateRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Requests\ProfilRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\ProfilPasswordRequest;

class AdminProfileController extends Controller
{ 
    public function update_profil(ProfilRequest $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validated();
        
        $user = $request->user();

        $user->fill($validated);
        
        $user->save();


        return redirect()->back()->with('toast', __('Success save'));
        //return Redirect::route('admin.profile.edit');
    }
}

I expect form validation to work without delay in real time

We don't see your TextInput component but judging by the name of your custom event i am going to assume you are using the same event on the actual input.
Consider Using @input instead of @change on the actual <input> and "debounce" the event. More info on the difference between the two events here, More info on debouncing here and here
regarding the delay, there is only a delay by the second and third inputs, maybe check the network tab to see what's going on
it can help if you share a repo
